# Can't hide/unhide Facebook comment through Post API

Tags: facebook, api, post, comments, hide

When I try to Hide Comment through Post API, I had received following error. Any solutions to resolve this error?

```
result = fb.Post(url, new
        {
            access_token = fanpage.AccessToken,
            is_hidden = false
        });
```

> Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #200) (#200) Can not hide or unhide this comment

Comment: are you using a page token of that page? are you sure it is possible to hide comments with the api?

Comment: I checked can_hide, return true but cant still hide/unhide